# html entities in a PHP code

Tags: php, html, entity

I have a homework and it's a webpage (log-in page) and the task is to enter and bypass the login forum, well the first thing I have looked into was the page's source and I found that if I want the username I should go to /page.phps directory and I did that. After entering that directory I was redirected to another page with this piece of code

```
<?php
$super_admin_access = false;
// Set our super-admin level user?
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
 $user = html_entity_decode($_GET['user']);
 if ($user === "<root>") {
   $super_admin_access = true;
 }
}
?>

<div class="logo"><img src="../assets/images/challenge-priserv-logo.svg" alt="Nethub logo"></div>

<div class="login">
  <form class="form" onsubmit="doLogin(); return false">
    <div class="message message-error" id="login-error-msg" style="display: none">Denied!</div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="label">Username</div>

      <input type="text" name="username">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="label">Password</div>

      <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <!-- In case I forget, details are at page.phps -->

    <div class="actions">
      <input type="submit" value="Access server" class="btn">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I don't know if I understand the php code in the right way, but what I firstly though of was writing the `"<root>"` in a html entity format which become `&#x22;&#x3C;root&#x3E;&#x22;`, especially that there was a hint saying

`Did you see the comment in the source code suggesting you take a look at page.phps? Take a look. What does urldecode do? Can you do the opposite of urldecode?`

So I tried to login using the username `"<root>"` or the encoded one `&quot;&lt;root&gt;&quot;` I tried removing the quota but no luck, I don't know if there is a password or something like that, I would appreciate any help given, thanks :).

Comment: Looked on the site. It is not using `html_entity_decode`, but it actually using `urldecode`. Visiting `login.php?user=%3Croot%3E` works.

Comment: it didn't show the flag

Comment: http://118.102.0.1/login?user=%3Croot%3E - This just worked for me

Comment: thank you so much it worked!

Comment: but i want to ask why it didn't work with the .php thing?

Comment: The game that you were using seems to be emulating a web server/browser. It is most likely to do with how they are processing the requests.

Comment: yeah you are right and thanks again for your great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as this is a piece of homework I won't give a direct answer, but rather point you in the right direction.

You are definitely on the right track, but you seem to have gotten a little confused with how PHP handles strings.

Let me give you an example. We go to the page `login.php?user=tom`.

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['user'];
$desiredUsername = "tom";
if ($user === $desiredUsername) {
    echo "You're in!";
}
```

Let's take a look at the check that `if()` is doing in this case.

```
$desiredUsername === "tom"; // true
$desiredUsername === "frank"; // false
$desiredUsername === "jonas"; // false
```

When you are setting the $user variable in your code, you are wrapping `<root>` with quotes like so.. `"<root>"`. While the PHP code checks to see if `$user === "<root>"`, the quotes in this case are actually just specifying that we want to see if `$user` contains the string `<root>`.

Test your method of using the encoded entities `&quot;&lt;root&gt;&quot;` with and without the quotes on either side and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried to go to `login.php?user=&quot;&lt;root&gt;&quot;` but it didn't work, I tried it with and without quotes but it didn't work, i think it's because it's a web game, i mean it's not an actual website, i think it's an error in the handler, also i can't edit the php code, i only have access to the page (within the game) and i think bypass the log in forum

Comment: i could give you the website if you are interested in trying it by yourself

Comment: yes i did try it multiple times, the website is game.cyberprotection.agency, if  you can message me @ adoobii25@gmail.com i will give you the username and password

Comment: You should defenitly not give your username and password to some guy on the internet

Comment: I agree with the above, but I am willing to help if he doesn't mind doing so. Change your password to something random before and after providing me with a password though.

Comment: i don't think there is change password option on the website xD

Answer (score 1):

First it's must be `$_GET['username']` NOT `$_GET['user']` because input field name is is `"username"` not `"user"`

Comment: I have tried to change it from the elements panel but it didn't work,

Comment: i mean the input field not the script

Answer (score 1):

Form's input's name is *username*, but it checks for *user*. To get access to the super-duper-mega admin powers, pass a query parameter in the url

```
http://yoururl/page.php?user=&lt;root&gt
```

Comment: it didn't workout, i think because the problem is a web game ( it's not an actualy website)